# Detect Windows Network Type

Tags: winapi

Does anyone know if there is any convinient Windows API function that can be used to determine the active Network Type. By network type I mean:

- Home
- Work
- Public

I would like to be able to inform the users of my software if they are on a public network, as it may cause connection issues in my software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if you are on a public network, you can check for the  `NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PUBLIC` value ([NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) using the [INetwork interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which is used to determine the properties of a network) and the  [`INetwork::GetCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

For more info about this topic try the [`Windows 7 Network Location`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17158) doc.

Comment: Although this does answer my question, the links you provided led me to find an even better solution. Rather than just checking the Network Location, there is a Windows Firewall API function that can be used to test if a port is allowed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365290(v=vs.85).aspx